# 22.04 LTS "sudo do-release-upgrade" does not work

Tags: 20.04, do-release-upgrade, 22.04

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -cd
```

returns

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '22.04' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Then

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

returns

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

I think the bug is:

22.04 is not marked as LTS. So `do-release-upgrade` does not work for the upgrade from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS.

Any workaround except `set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.`?

Comment: There is **no bug** as that is expected behavior.  The upgrade path from 20.04 to 22.04 does **not** open until **after** the release of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS which is still ~three months into the future.   It's the same as prior LTS releases & upgrades (*and exactly as documentation states*).

Comment: If you check back on prior *release-upgrade* cycle; Canonical/Ubuntu have provided blogs on how to upgrade without waiting... but you'll note the date of when blog is posted varies (ie. 16.04->18.04 was a different time frame to 18.04->20.04) as the Ubuntu Release Team provide input on the blog's release, and it only occurs **after** they deem it has a good chance of success (*full success is when they open the path*).  If you watched the release; whilst it went rather smoothly; there are still known/issues, the earliest should be fixed Monday (via upgrades), others will likely take longer

Comment: Linking back to the documentation stating this would be helpful @guiverc - I didn't know this!

Comment: @toonarmycaptain I wasn't thinking of a single wiki/help/blog post at ubuntu.com; but it's found in many places... The [release announcement for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/04/21/ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-released/) actually state "*Users of Ubuntu 21.10 will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to 22.04. Users of 20.04 LTS will be offered the automatic upgrade when 22.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 4th of August. For further information about upgrading, see:*"..

Comment: @toonarmycaptain  I'm on the Ubuntu News team (since 2015) thus see most posts for UWN purposes, then tend to forget them, though tend to recall details even if not URLs; but a search engine would be required by me too for much of that now, so I'll suggest you try. I picked on example I used and found https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today  for the 18.04->20.04 blog but they'll all be there.. though help/wiki pages on upgrade are often paragraphs on pages about other things release related.  I'll suggest using `site:*.ubuntu.com` in searches

Comment: @guiverc fair enough :) I hope I didn't come across harshly; I really would have expected something like this to be be documented if it's SOP (outside of blog posts! Maybe the [release cycle page](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) could note this. 
Thanks for your work :)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In case you're coming from **21.10**: The [Jammy Jellyfish Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668) (from 2022-04-21) contain a note on *Upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10*:

> Upgrades to 22.04 LTS are currently not enabled (due a bug with snapd and update-notifier) but will be in the next couple of days

In case you're coming from **20.04 LTS**: Ubuntu 20.04 will not detect a newer version until Ubuntu 22.04.1 is released, which is [scheduled for 2022-08-04](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906).

From [Ubuntu Server Upgrading](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/upgrade-introduction):

> Upgrades from one LTS to the next LTS release are only available after the first point release. For example, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will only upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after the 20.04.1 point release. If users wish to update before the point release (e.g. on a subset of machines to evaluate the LTS upgrade) users can force the upgrade via the -d flag.

Comment: I can understand your answer, thank you. But why? It is confusing. What is the difference between xx.04 and xx.04.1?

Comment: I think the decision is about stability. Users who run an LTS release often don't need bleeding edge features but prefer stable operation. Whenever a new major version of a software is released, there's a chance of breaking something. The first bugfix release xx.04.1 contains fixes for problems in xx.04, e.g. bugs that occured after upgrading to xx.04 (using `-d`). These bugs can be found and fixed until xx.04.01, so there's a higher chance for a stable update.

Comment: @jack The whole point of a stable release, should be that enough testing has been done to release it as "stable". In any case, no OSes are really stable. Bugs keep appearing. I feel this point release constraint is redundant. the LTS "release" should be the stable version to update to.

Comment: Still missing, is there a delay or a bug?

Comment: See this announcement on the Ubuntu forum: [Ubuntu 22.04.1 delayed until August 11](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-22-04-1-delayed-until-august-11/29859)

Comment: The [Jammy Jellyfish (22.04.1 LTS) Point-Release Status Tracking](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-22-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/29102) page is a live document on the current release status.

Comment: so what is the solution now?

Comment: The problem does no longer occur since August 11, 2022.