# Can I upgrade Ubuntu (specifically either 20.04 or 21.10) to 22.04 using the ISO file?

Tags: updates, iso

As above, upgrading to 2204.
Thanks.

Have downloaded the (desktop) ISO, sitting on my Desktop. Can I then mount it and use it directly (without burning to DVD/USB), to upgrade the OS??

Comment: You've not actually asked any question!   Title may **not** be readable on many devices that view the site, so please correct your question.

Comment: You can *upgrade via re-install* using the ISO; it's most useful for Desktop systems, but you've not provided any clues as to if you're talking about Desktop or Server installs - as the effects differ.  It's very smooth if you have no 3rd party packages on your system (*QA-testing of the procedure is done only using Ubuntu repository software*)

Comment: my experience for desktop x64 was an option to install side by side and choose on boot. I declined. if you do, do a Clonezilla or other complete disk/partition backup. I was under the impression that LTS for 20.04 would not require a new complete install for a 'better' 22.x version. ahh see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403616/22-04-lts-sudo-do-release-upgrade-does-not-work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Ubuntu from ISO image directly from hard disk of a system running Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux)

Comment: FYI:  The [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668) state rather clearly "*There are no offline upgrade options for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server.*"  ... thus the *upgrade via re-install* is what I mentioned before... it's not really an upgrade; but is a re-install that doesn't touch your changes/settings/files & auto-reinstalls your *manually installed* packages automatically if from Ubuntu repositories...  see my prior comment